# broken images on browser

Tags: image, browser

So, there's this blog I visit often, and it has a lot of pictures. 
But the thing is, they are all broken. The image is there, and I found that if I use a proxy server and access the blog, some pictures are there. Some are still broken, so then I have to right click the broken image, copy the image URL, open the URL in a different tab/windows, and once that picture finishes loading, I refresh the blog, and the picture I loaded on a different windows now shows.... 
Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can get it fixed?? Thanks.

In case you don't understand what I mean, This is the blog that makes this happen

http://wersierre.tumblr.com/

This applies to Firefox, chrome, IE in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very likely to be the case that the target server is configured to prevent **hotlinking**. When accessing the images via the page you posted, the HTTP response code of the images is 403, it indicates the server can be reached and understood the HTTP request, but refuses to take any further action.

Comment: Is there any way to fix fix this, or make it show the image?

Comment: I am afraid you have to store your own copy of the images elsewhere (e.g. imagehost) but not to link to the target server directly.